# C# LoadReport error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have developed an application in C# using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. It loads reports from a report folder kept with the application.
I have kept two reports in the folder. The application loads both the reports on the DEV machine, but on the client machine, it has only opened one report and gives me an error while loading the second report as Load report failed.

I am stuck badly. I have checked the path, but not able to identify the error.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>   CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in
>   the C++ stack.    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object&
>   DocumentPath, Int32 Options)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)    at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String
>   filename)    at Sbi_Bank_Cheque.Form1.button4_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: possibly the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654154/unsupported-operation-a-document-processed-by-the-jrc-engine-cannot-be-opened-i and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833894/a-document-processed-by-the-jrc-engine-cannot-be-opened-in-the-c-stack

Comment: I changed the Font "MICR" for something more classic (Arial) and the reports start to work well.

Apparently this Font has some conflict with Crystal Report export routine.